# Split string by multiple delimiters and exclude splitting by others

Tags: javascript

I would like to split a string by either `*`, `/`, `+` or `-` and exclude using '`` as a delimiter. So given the string `9.5+5*4/2.2`, I want my result to be `["9.5", "5", "4", "2.2"]`. However, I currently get the result `["9", "5", "5", "4", "2", "2"]`.

This is what I have tried:

```js
const test = '9.5+5*4/2.2'
const signs = ['*', '+', '-', '/']
console.log(test.split(/[*+-/]/))
```

Answer (score 3):

`+-/` was treated as a range of values, which includes `.`. See [here](https://www.ascii-code.com/), in the ASCII table. `+` is 43 and `/` is 47. Since `.` is 46, it is included in the range.

To prevent `-` from being treated as a range, move it to the end of the character set:

```js
const test = '9.5+5*4/2.2'
const signs = ['*', '+', '-', '/']
console.log(test.split(/[*+/-]/))
```